# How to make Flex Accordion slide from one pane to another?

Tags: apache-flex, animation

If you add an Accordion navigation component to Flex Application, like this:

```
    <mx:Accordion x="14" y="570" width="321" height="200">
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Accordion Pane 1" width="100%" height="100%">
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Accordion Pane 2" width="100%" height="100%">
        </s:NavigatorContent>
    </mx:Accordion>
```

then your Accordion's panes will jump open and closed instantly.

Question is: what code should I write to make my Accordion's panes switching animated?
(Like in Adobe's demo called Tour de Flex)

To see what I mean by animated switching between panes:
1) go here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flex/tourdeflex/web/
2) select Other Components -> Containers -> Super Accordion in the left pane
3) click on Super Accordion's pane headers and see them moving

Thanks!

Comment: You can have a look at the source code: http://code.google.com/p/tink/source/browse/trunk/flex4/mx/src/ws/tink/mx/containers/superAccordion/SuperAccordionHeader.as

Comment: @hering: This source code gives non-animated Accordion in Flex 4, I'll explain why below in this question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add 'openDuration' attribute to 'Accordion'. The number should be in milliseconds.
FTQuest

Comment: thanks, it works. Sorry, can't upvote your answer since I am anonymous user :( Flex 4 default theme (spark) has default value for openDuration equal to zero. Same value for Flex 3 default theme (mx) is 250 - hence my confusion.